# How can I ensure that a method is called (once, if present) for every class in a hierarchy?

Tags: python, inheritance, super, method-resolution-order

I have a class hierarchy in which subclasses may optionally define a method with a given name, say `do_it`, and want to write a function, say `do_all`, in the base class that ensures that each such method will be executed, in order of class hierarchy. The closest I can get to achieving this is something like:

```
class A(object):
    def do_it(self):
        print 'Do A'

    def do_all(self):
        # Better, from comments and answers: vars(type(self))
        for c in reversed(self.__class__.__mro__[:-1]):
            c.do_it(self)

class B(A):
    def do_it(self):
        print 'Do B'

class C(B):
    def no_do_it(self):
        pass

class D(C):
    def do_it(self):
        print 'Do D'
```

This almost works as intended, for example `B().do_all()` gives

```
Do A
Do B
```

But it results in a duplicate call to `B`s `do_it` for all classes descended from it. For example `D().do_all()` gives

```
Do A
Do B
Do B
Do D
```

How can I avoid the duplicate call to a parent's `do_it` from classes that do not implement it? Is this even the right way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why the call to `super`?  wouldn't `c.do_it(self)` work?

Comment: @mgilson: Um, of course it does!

Comment: may I ask about your real use case ???

Comment: Like @bruno I'm also curious about your use case... Personally I'd also use `inspect.getmro(...)` instead of the dunders

Comment: @JonClements: Can you explain the preference for `inspect.getmro(...)`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius it reads much better as to intent - and will work with both old and new style classes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check whether the function has already been seen:

```
def do_all(self):
    seen = set()
    for c in reversed(self.__class__.__mro__[:-1]):
        if c.do_it not in seen:
            seen.add(c.do_it)
            c.do_it(self)
```

Note that in Python 2 you'll need to extract the function from the unbound method, as `c.do_it.__func__` (or use `six.get_unbound_function`).

An alternative is to examine `__dict__`:

```
def do_all(self):
    for c in reversed(self.__class__.__mro__[:-1]):
        if 'do_it' in c.__dict__:
            c.do_it(self)
```

Comment: I really like the `__dict__` idea. That seems to exactly convey the intent. Is there any reason to avoid that (it seems like it should the featured part of the answer, rather than an alternative)?

Comment: Was about to post with the `c.__dict__` solution.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius : given the spec I don't see any reason to not go for the dict solution - it's the most straightforward one, as it just plain bypasses inheritance. The only potential problem - but you'll get it anyway - is if someone actually calls on `super(...).do_it()` in it's own implementation of `do_it`, in which case you'll still get two calls...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Is there a reason to prefer `__dict__` over `vars()`?

Comment: Nope, that's just the same in this case. In fact `vars()` should be prefered just like it's "better" to use `type(obj)` instead of `obj.__class__` etc - generic function over direct "magic" attribute access.